# Can not import font into mjml

Tags: import, fonts, path, html-email, mjml

mj-font does not work in mjml.

Here is what I am trying to do in `index.mjml`:

```
<mjml>

  <mj-head>
      <mj-font name="testFont" href="testFont.ttf"/>
  </mj-head>

  <mj-body>

    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>

        <mj-text font-family="testFont" align="center" font-size="20px">
          Just a text
        </mj-text>

      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>

  </mj-body>

</mjml>
```

Here is the screenshot of the project directory:
[image]

Here is what I see in the app:
[image]

And here is what the font should look like:
[image]

What am I missing here and how could I make my font work?

Thank you.

Comment: mj-font can only accept external font files, it will not work with local variants.

Answer (score 13):

I have found it difficult to use custom fonts using the mj-font tag. If you use a google font api it seems to work correctly.

Example using Google font

```
<mj-font name="Raleway" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" />
```

Taking that into consideration, I have started to using the following and has worked for me: (it goes between `<mj-style></mj-style>` tags)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: testFont;
    src: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/199900/fonts/someFontFile.ttf)
    format('truetype');
}
```

I would normally use a .woff file instead of a .ttf file.

Diving deeper into it, if you go to a Google font link such as https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway in your web browser, the contents of the file is this:

```
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v13/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCMIT4ttDfCmxA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v13/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0IT4ttDfA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Back to your problem... Since the file that you are loading with the `<mj-font>` tag is a binary file, I would imagine that mjml doesn't know how to process it. If the file were a .woff font file then it might work. Perhaps they could change this in the near future. After all, it is a very useful tool.